# making button clickable when form is filled in html

Tags: javascript, html, button

I made a form in html and want the user to be able to press submit when some fields are filled. So my button is disabled in the beginning, but for some reason my button doesn't become clickable when things are filled.
This is the form in my html:

```
 <fieldset>
        <legend>U gegevens</legend>
        <form name="signup" action="index.html" method="post">
            <ul>
                <li> <label>Naam</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" size="30" />
                </li>
                <li> <label>Voornaam</label>
                    <input type="text" name="voornaam" size="30" />
                </li>
                <li> <label>Adress</label>
                    <input type="text" name="adress" size="30" />
                </li>
                <li> <label>Gemeente</label>
                    <input type="text" name="gemeente" size="30" />
                </li>
                <li> <label>Postcode</label>
                    <input type="text" name="postcode" size="30" />
                </li>
                <li>
                <p>Ik wens een alternatief facturatieadres <input type="checkbox" id="be1"onclick="if(this.checked){displayFac()}"></p>
                </li>
                <li style="display:none;" id="fac1"> <label >Adress</label>
                    <input type="text" size="30" />
                </li>
                <li style="display:none;" id="fac2"> <label >Gemeente</label>
                    <input type="text" size="30" />
                </li>
                <li style="display:none;" id="fac3"> <label>Postcode</label>
                    <input type="text" size="30" />
                </li>
                <li>
                <p>Ik wens een alternatief leveringsadress <input type="checkbox" id="be2" onclick="if(this.checked){displayLe()}"></p>
                </li>
                <li style="display:none;" id="le1"> <label >Adress</label>
                    <input type="text" size="30" />
                </li>
                <li style="display:none;" id="le2"> <label>Gemeente</label>
                    <input type="text" size="30" />
                </li>
                <li style="display:none;" id="le3" > <label>Postcode</label>
                    <input type="text" size="30" />
                </li>
                <li><label for="submit"></label>
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" disabled>Verzenden</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
```

And this is the javascript i use to check if there is something filled:

```
function validateForm()
{
  while (true){
    var a=document.forms["signup"]["name"].value;
    var b=document.forms["signup"]["voornaam"].value;
    var c=document.forms["signup"]["adress"].value;
    var d=document.forms["signup"]["gemeente"].value;
    var e=document.forms["signup"]["postcode"].value;
    if (a!=null && a!="" && b !=null && b!="" && c!=null && c!= "" && d!=null && d!=""   && e!=null && e!="")
    {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled=false;
    }
 }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your function will freeze the browser forever.  You never actually called your function, so you aren't noticing that problem.

Comment: How are you calling the function that enables the button?  `validateForm()`... and SLaks is right... `while(true)` will always be true, creating an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the while loop from **validateForms()** function and call it on every inputs **[onblur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)** event and also if the checkbox checked. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function validateForm()
{

    var a=document.forms["signup"]["name"].value;
    var b=document.forms["signup"]["voornaam"].value;
    var c=document.forms["signup"]["adress"].value;
    var d=document.forms["signup"]["gemeente"].value;
    var e=document.forms["signup"]["postcode"].value;
    if ( a!="" &&  b!="" &&  c!= ""  && d!=""    && e!="")
    {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled=false;
    }


}
```